How to improve this script to find specific file
I have this one line bash script that does part of what I need, but not quite; so I hope someone can help me figure this out....
The script I have looks into dozens of subdirectories that qualify for what I need: a file named 'name' that contains 8Q:
find ../../devices -type f -name "name" -exec grep -q 8Q {} \; -printf '%h\n'

But I also need it to look for file named 'available_instances' that contains the number 1. There are dozens of these subdirectories, but many of them will contain 0, meaning they cannot be used.
How can I extend this script to do that?
TIA,
rick

Are both conditions required, or do you want to print the names of directories meeting at least one condition?

could any of the files named name contain the string 1?  if you find matches for both files in the same directory do you want to print the directory name one or twice?

Use -o for multiple conditions :
find ../../devices -type f \(\
    -name "name"                -exec grep -q 8Q {} \;\
    -o\
    -name "available_instances" -exec grep -q 1  {} \;\
    \) -printf '%h\n'


thank you Philippe; I will try that!
